# How do I use text from an EditText?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a basic dialer app with an EditText containing the number that a user inputs, and a button telling the app to make the call. The id for the EditText is callNumber and the buttons id is callButton. What do I put in the MainActivity.java file to make it call the number in the EditText?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/callNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/example" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/callButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/call" />

</LinearLayout>

package com.BigTooth.Apps.dialer;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callButton);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
                    startActivity(callIntent);

                }

            });

    }
}
```

Comment: Put the code so that we can understand the problem more accurately

Comment: It wont let me add the code. I'm on the mobile website.

Comment: You please try my code..It will work..

Comment: I did and it said my ide told me there were errors.

Comment: what are the errors you are getting???

Comment: You said you want to call that number which was entered in the edittext..But you are not doing like that..

Comment: what is the name of your layout file??? is it activity_main.xml or just main.xml???

Answer (score 1):

Hope that you have put your `EditText` and `Button` in `fragment_main.xml`

So,Put this code in your `onCreateView`

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
EditText et=(EditText)rootView.findViewByID(callNumber);
Button b=(Button)rootView.findViewByID(callButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
       Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
       callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + et.getText().toString()));
       startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
return rootView;
```

Must add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` in Manifest as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText callNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.callNumber);
String num = callNumber.getText().toString();
//this gets the number in edittext


@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
```

Also don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

EDIT

Implement OnClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Exchange this line with `public class MainActivity extends Activity{`.

Comment: It didn't tell me there were any errors, but it kept crashing on start up.

Comment: You didn't implement OnclickListener. See the edit.

Comment: It still crashes on start